# Android: Launching camera app now crashes app

Tags: java, android, camera

It was working fine, and i'm not too sure what i've changed to make it stop working. When I load the camera it works fine, it's on the return to the page that it fails. I've tried removing what happens on the return leg of the photo to see if that's making it fall over, but it's really not working.

Here is my error:

```
10-19 16:01:43.455: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:43.455: E/Asset Sub Group(5309): 1
10-19 16:01:43.480: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:43.480: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:47.045: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:47.055: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:47.055: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:47.300: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5309): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-19 16:01:52.315: W/dalvikvm(5309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c721f8)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.directenquiries.assessment.tool/com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset} did not call through to super.onStop()
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:4673)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1194)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-19 16:01:52.320: E/AndroidRuntime(5309):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Heres my code:

```
public void startCamera() 
    {
        File photo = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
               {
                   photo = new File(Global.Pictures + timestamp +".png");

               } 
        else 
               {
                   photo = new File(getCacheDir(), FOLDER_NAME+File.separator+timestamp+".png");
               }    
        if (photo != null) 
               {
                   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                   selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CALLBACK);
               }

    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

      String PhotoDescription = DBFunctions.GetObjectName(StationObjectID);
      String PhotoDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()); 

 }

    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

       Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Photo Capture Cancelled";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is `SuperNotCalledException`.

You just miss a `super.onStop()` call.

> Activity {com.directenquiries.assessment.tool/com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset} did not call through to super.onStop()

Comment: Hi, I don't have that on any page. Where should it be?

Comment: In your package `com.directenquiries.assessment.tool` you have an class named `AddAsset` than overrides `onStop()` but does not call `super.onStop()` as said in the exception error message.

Comment: Hey I have the class AddAsset but i've just done a search for the entire project for onStop and i don't have it anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

In the exception stands: `android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.directenquiries.assessment.tool/com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset} did not call through to super.onStop()`

Have you got an onStop() method? There you have to call super.onStop().

Comment: Hey I have the class AddAsset but i've just done a search for the entire project for onStop and i don't have it anywhere!